# Deploying an MVC3 application on IIS7 always returns Http 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, deployment, asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to deploy my MVC3 application on IIS7, on every URL I am getting an Http 500 - Internal Server Error.

The site runs fine in development in Visual Studio.
And I can request simple html pages, or aspx pages, and they return fine.
I've tested if asp.net works by adding an aspx page that returns inline <%= DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>, which also works fine.
So I think the problem is situated with MVC itself or the Routing.

MVC3 is installed on the server, but I also tried bin deploying by setting all MVC related references to `copy local = true`.

Any ideas ?

Edit:

I enabled failed request tracing, which results in no error logs.

Customerrors are off & Server errors are detailed :

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

The only thing I am getting is a 500 - Internal Server Error header with a blank page.

I checked the event log for the webserver, nothing to find.

After some restarts I'm getting a somewhat more detailed error :

[image: http500]

Comment: You need to go to the Application logs or failed request trace logs and find out what the actual error is. There's no way at all to help you without knowing that.

Comment: While debugging your site you can set IIS to display the full 500 error message to remote requests. Go to the site in IIS, Error Pages, Edit Feature Settings and check 'Detailed errors'. Remember to turn it back to custom error pages for remote requests before you go live though.

Comment: detailed errors are enabled in the web.config  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

Comment: So what's the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm getting nothing, just a 500 header with a blank page.

Comment: I also enabled request trace logging for the site, but there are no logs generated.

Comment: This sounds like a configuration issue.  Can you include you're web.config settings? Are you using Classic or Integrated App pool?

Comment: Please step by step configure iis for asp.net mvc3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087586/configuring-iis-windows-7-for-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Have you installed MVC3 update on server, if no you can install from http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 500 error on on every URL means that the error occurred at a very early state, like app start and your request haven't even handled by the request pipeline. Check your MVC environment and make sure all dependent library have been installed correctly. It's very difficult to tell what's going wrong without seeing the actual error message.

Good luck