# View in Browser for MVC 3 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In Visual Studio 2010, you can right-click an aspx page in a web forms app, or on the web forms app itself in the solution explorer, and you get "View in Browser" in your context menu.

In ASP.NET MVC projects, this item doesn't seem to be available in the context menu. The only way I know to run the app is to set the MVC app as a startup project and hit CTRL+F5. But, if there are two MVC apps in the solution, this doesn't really work. How do you accomplish this for mvc apps?

In my scenario, There are multiple users working on application on different controllers/view, How could they execute their view without changes the routes in Global.asax ?

Comment: You can host the applications on IIS.

Comment: How can I host the application on IIS ?

Comment: Refer to the following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087586/configuring-iis-windows-7-for-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-3) for details about using IIS instead of Cassini.

Comment: Do you need to debug both or just view both?

Comment: I need to debug both controller and views associated with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fundamental difference between MVC and Web Forms, and is crucial that you "get" this difference.

In Web Forms, everything revolves around the page.  You can right click an aspx page and "view in browser" because there is a 1:1 correlation between the page and the URL.  The page is at the top of the request, so to speak.

In MVC, everything revolves around the controller.  The view is not part of the URL in any way, it's merely a template used by the controller to render the output.  You can choose to have any action method render any view you want, it's not tied directly to the request.

Since the "view" is completely disconnected from the request, there is no option to "view in browser", because doing so makes absolutely no sense.  You don't "view" views, they are templates that are rendered by the controller action method.

Comment: I knew this all, but what could be the option to handle controllers ? Have you got my scenario ?

Comment: @SheikhMuhammadHaris - Visual Studio 2012 has a new feature called the Page Inspector, which will do this.  It doesn't exist in 2010 though.

Comment: Oh, so I have to install VS 2012 first. In-fact Windows 7 :) Anyways, Thanks for your answer and comments @Mystere Man