# HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Working on a MVC5 project, I have access to the account / login page. When I enter wrong credentials it tells me that the username / password is incorrect. When I enter the right credentials it redirects me to home/index so I assume the login did work.

How ever upon getting to the new page I get the following error.
HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized.

Ant i'm not sure how I would go on and solve this.

My Login Controller

```
public ActionResult LogIn()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

And my model

```
public class LogOnModel {
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public interface IFormsAuthenticationService {
    void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie);
    void SignOut();
}

public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthenticationService {
    public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    }
```

And last my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SaleswebEntities" connectionString=
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>        
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The connection string is not empty, but I did remove it I do not want it posted public.

Comment: Please show your code from action and controller. The fact that you are redirected doesn't mean you are authenticated.

Comment: @Kamo sorry for that, updated my post.

Comment: What does your `FormsService.SignIn()` method do?

Comment: public interface IFormsAuthenticationService {
        void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie);
        void SignOut();
    }

Comment: I mean could you add its code too? :)

Comment: @Kamo Done, Sorry about that.

Comment: Seems ok. The last thing - can you post your web.config?

Comment: @Kamo Done. The connection string is not empty, I just did not want to post it public.

Comment: @Kamo This is a old mvc3 project that i'm trying to redo in a mvc5 application. How ever I believe it's not possible. Atleast not with my skill set.

Comment: What does your Home Controller look like? If you are accessing an action within your Index action with the Authorized attribute and you did not pass any type of authentication you will get a 401 error.

Comment: Can you post your Index action?

Comment: Do you mean you can land on Home page but going to "NewPage" is giving the unauthorized error code? Do you have any kind of Authorization applied on Controller(s)/Locations?

Comment: What is the new page you are trying to reach, and the controller code for that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a simular issue and it were nothing with the code, something did happen with my iis and I had to reinstall it. The key thing here is to make sure you uninstall the Windows Process Activation Service or otherwise your ApplicationHost.config will be still around.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you use `FormsService` in your Login Controller. I think that this class is SharePoint-specific. I would recommend using `WebSecurity.Login()` or `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate()` instead.

Comment: Isn't that @Joakim Carlsson own service as defined in 'IFormsAuthenticationService' ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your Startup.cs has configured the application correctly?

There should be something similar to the following in there:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a `IIS` permission issue, you should try running VS as administrator if you have not already.

**" HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page."**

[Diagnose 401.x HTTP errors on IIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/07/14/howto-diagnose-iis-401-access-denied.aspx)

Try to make sure permissions are correct for the folders.
Double-click the Authentication feature in IIS. Right-click the `"Anonymous Authentication"` provider and select edit.  Now, right-click the web application in the left pane, select Edit Permissions..., select the Security tab, click Edit -> Add and add `IIS APPPOOL\NameOfAppPool`. Make sure the Application Pool Identity has read and execute permissions of the folder.

Here are a few links.

[Configuring IIS (Windows 7) for ASP.NET / ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087586/configuring-iis-windows-7-for-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-3/5087652#5087652)

http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-http-error-401-0-unauthorized

https://serverfault.com/questions/348049/iis-and-http-401-0-unauthorized

Comment: Hi Rich, Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've rolled back your most recent addition, since it seems to be little more than a copy-paste from another resource. Instead, we prefer answers to be tailored to the particular question. Note that the answer, in it's current form, is perfectly fine; you have a +1 from me!